# do platelets cytoplasm contains DNA?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology

I'm a 12th-grade student and I have an entrance exam this year.

I have a question in biology. I would appreciate you if you help me <3

as we thoroughly know platelets are multiple pieces of a big cell which is called megacaryocyte so they do not have any nucleus. so I wanna know if they cytoplasm contains any type of DNA or not? I'm sure that without the nucleus there can't be any linear DNA but I doubt on the cycle DNA.

thank you